# Displaying routes that do not exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting a really strange problem which I can't solve.  Everything worked fine yesterday but today it does not.  I am building an API and I have the following in my route file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function() {
        Route::post('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
    });
});
```

There are no other routes in my route file - I have double checked using vim via putty.

Anyway, if I visit the route of my url, I am shown the default Laravel 5 welcome page.  Strange thing is, I have deleted welcome.blade.php from my server and it still displays!

If I try posting to my API route using Postman, where yesterday I was being returned a token, today I get

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

I have tried clearing caches without success.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  Or maybe knows what the problem could be?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure there is no other appilcation running in your machine? You are running withe artisan serve? try to change the port and test again

Comment: It is set up as a virtual host.  Is there any way to see if it is loading it from another file?

Comment: can you run `php artisan serve` in the application directory? if you can't you need to debug your hosts

Comment: This is on a live server.

Comment: so you need to find ... there is another application in the server? can you change the 'welcome' page to debug or something like that?

Comment: I dont see a welcome page in any of the projects on the server.  None of my routes work

Comment: Push your project to a public git, I'll pull it and look at it. Tag me with `@` when it's ready.

Comment: what do you see when you run `php artisan route:list` ? Can you share the ouput?